# Linear SVM is used for linearly separating the data which have two features

Tags: machine-learning, svm, knn

Can we use KNN and linear SVM classifier for training the model with data which contains 4 features and have 6 classification clusters? Because what i think that linear SVM and KNN are used for linearly separating the data which have two features and have binary classification cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you just need to use OneVsAll wrapper, like this one https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html
Essentially you will train 6 classifiers, one per cluster, which seeks to locate one class from all the rest.